# Remove attr only if it was made with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that on `mouseover` will add attr class this.
if a selected tab was selected and the page was reloaded with it, it has class this

I want that on `mouseout` I will be able to remove the added class only if it was the one I have just added and not the one that was load with the page - how can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to do it. One way is to use data.

```
$("whatever").mouseover(function (){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("someClass")) {
    $(this).addClass("someClass").data("addedByMe",true);
  }
});

$("whatever").mouseout(function (){
   if ($(this).data("addedByMe") == true){
      $(this).removeClass("someClass");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two calss names (such as `selected` and `focused`).

So when you selected a tab, you add the `selected` class to it. The mouse over and out event alter the `focused` class only.

You could set both `selected` and `focused` to have the same CSS rule set or not if you want.

```
$(".menu-item").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("focused");
  // or if you don't want the effect affect the selected item, use the following:
  // if(!$(this).hasClass("selected")) { $(this).addClass("focused"); }
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("focused");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable on page load.

```
var isClassAppliedAtLoad = false;

if ($("#yourelement").hasClass("yourclassname")) {
    isClassAppliedAtLoad = true;
}
```

and in your mouseover event you can check the variable.